# Writing to disk a struct that contains a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a struct in C that looks like this:

```
struct Database {
    int row_size;
    int name_size; 
    struct Address *;
};
```

This struct will be put into the heap via a malloc(...) call. I will then have `struct Address*` point to another region in the heap via another malloc(...) call.

If I use fwrite(...) to write this struct to disk, what will happen? Will fwrite(...) automatically follow (or dereference) the pointer `struct Address *`, or will it simply copy the pointer itself (which would be useless) to disk?

Comment: Simply try and see what happens. And that's the answer.

Comment: yes, but that would require more time and effort than someone on SE telling me the answer.

Comment: `struct Address*` - the pointer already means it's an address. What's your intention with naming the struct `Address`?

Comment: I am doing an exercise in the book LCTHW. It wants me to make a database with a variable number of records (aka addresses -- this database stores addresses).

Comment: What does the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html) for `fwrite` say?

Comment: Well, it's useless to copy the pointer itself, so i assumed that any good compiler would think you mean the heap memory pointed to by the pointer, not the pointer itself. This exercise is now a lot harder, and i don't know how to do it. ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fwrite will write the memory content of your structure, meaning it will simply copy the pointer itself to disk, which would be useless in your own term.